# Corollary about semidirect products.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\bar{m}$ have exponent $k$ in $Z^x_n$, and let $\alpha : Z_k \rightarrow Z^x_n$ be the homomorphism that takes the generator to $\bar{m}$. Then writing $Z_n = \langle b \rangle$, $Z_k = \langle a \rangle$, and identifying $Z^x_n$ with $\operatorname{Aut}(Z_n)$, we obtain
>
> $$Z_n \rtimes_{\alpha} Z_k = \{b^ia^j | 0 \leq i < n, 0 \leq j < k\},$$ where b has order n, a has order k, and the multiplication is given by $$b^ia^jb^{i'}a^{j'}  = b^{i+m^ji'}a^{j+j'}.$$

I am a bit confused with the phrase "identifying $Z^x_n$ with $Aut(Z_n)$". What exactly does that mean?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By "Let $\bar{m}$ have exponent k in $Z^x_n$" you meant $\,m\,$ is an element of order $\,k\,$ in the group $\,\Bbb Z_n^*\,$ ?

Comment: The group isomorphism  $\,\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_n)\cong \Bbb Z_n^*\,$ is, apparently, what confuses you.

Comment: @DonAntonio The textbook defines "exponent" as "Let G be a group and let $n \in Z$. We say that $g \in G$ has exponent n if $g^n=e$". So it's not necessarily the order.

Comment: Please note that $\LaTeX$ editing I did to the text of your question.

Comment: @Artus, what book is that, please? I think some minimality requirement could probably be considered there...

Comment: @DonAntonio It's on page 31, Def. 2.5.11...http://www.albany.edu/~mark/algebra.pdf

Comment: Yes, you're right @Artus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $\Bbb{Z}_{n}^{x}$ is really $\Bbb{Z}_{n}^{\star}$, the group (under multiplication) of invertible elements of $\Bbb{Z}_{n}$.

Now each automorphism of the (multiplicatively written) group $\Bbb{Z}_{n} = \langle b \rangle$ is indeed of the form $b \mapsto b^{s}$, for $\bar{s} \in \Bbb{Z}_{n}^{\star}$.

Moreover, the map
$$
\Bbb{Z}_{n}^{\star} \to \operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_{n})
\qquad
\bar{s} \mapsto (b \mapsto b^ {s})
$$
is an isomorphism of groups, that is, the required *identification*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, for example, for $Z_4$, we have $Z_4 = \{0, 1 ,2, 3\}$ and $Z^x_4 = \{1, 3\}$. But then for $b \rightarrow b^s$, s is only allowed to be 1 or 3, right because that's what's in $Z^x_4$?

Comment: @Artus, in your post you were using a multiplicative notation for $\Bbb{Z}_{n}$, so I used it as well. Now you are using additive notation. So you are right that $s = 1, 3$ here, only the automorphism is now $x \mapsto x s$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how I'm using additive notation. When we are talking about an element being a "unit" we're talking about elements that have multiplicative inverses, right?

Comment: @Artus, yes, but then you wrote $Z_n = \langle b \rangle$, and wrote powers $b^{j}$.

Comment: But where did I use addition? I thought $Z_4$ was defined to be the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. Then we say that $Z_4=<1>$, right? So here 1 generates $Z_4$ by addition, right? Is that what you're saying? But now I'm wondering how $Z_4$ could possibly be generated by multiplication. If we choose 1, we will only generate 1, because we will keep taking powers of it, right? If we choose 2, we will only get 0 and 2. And if we choose 3, we will only get 1 and 3. So how would it be possible for $Z_4$ to be generated multiplicatively?

Comment: @Artus, you used addition when you wrote, in your first comment, $\Bbb{Z}_{4} = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. So here we are talking $\Bbb{Z}_{4}$ as the integers modulo $4$. As an additive group, this is generated wither by $1$ or by $3$. In the question you are (also) using $\Bbb{Z}_{4}$ to denote an abstract cyclic group of order $n$, multiplicatively written, and generated by an element $b$.

Comment: Oh ok. So we can't know what b is, right? Since it is "abstract"?

Comment: What we do know is that if $\langle b \rangle \to \Bbb{Z}_{4}$ is an isomorphism, then $b$ is mapped to $1$ or $3$.